# Using 'define' in Scheme

Tags: scheme, definition

I'm new to Scheme and was just curious about 'define'. I've seen things like:
`(define (square x) (* x x))`
which makes sense [Function name 'square' input parameter 'x']. However, I found some example code from the 90's and am trying to make sense of:
`(define (play-loop-iter strat0 strat1 count history0 history1 limit) (~Code for function~)`
Except for the function name, are all of those input parameters?

Comment: yes, they are input parameters...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer - yes, all the symbols after the first one are parameters for the procedure (the first one being the procedures's name). Also it's good to point out that this:

```
(define (f x y)
  (+ x y))
```

Is just syntactic sugar for this, and both forms are equivalent:

```
(define f
  (lambda (x y)
    (+ x y)))
```

In general - you use the special form `define` for binding a *name* to a *value*, that value can be any data type available, including in particular functions (lambdas).

A bit more about parameters and procedure definitions - it's good to know that the `.` notation can be used for defining procedures with a variable number of arguments, for example:

```
(define (f . x) ; here `x` is a list with all the parameters
  (apply + x))

(f 1 2 3 4 5)   ; 0 or more parameters can be passed
=> 15
```

And one final trick with `define` (not available in all interpreters, but works in Racket). A quick shortcut for defining procedures that return procedures, like this one:

```
(define (f x)
  (lambda (y)
    (+ x y)))
```

... Which is equivalent to this, shorter syntax:

```
(define ((f x) y)
  (+ x y))

((f 1) 2)
=> 3
```

Comment: I accepted sepp's answer only cuz he was first. I really appreciate the extra info, Oscar :)

Comment: Fair enough, although it's good to point out the criteria for [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/170230) answers (under: Which answer should I choose?) ;)

Comment: I also like to do like this: `{ define 'x (* x x) }`. Then i can do: `'2 ; => 4` :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `strat0` through `limit` are the parameters of the `play-loop-iter` function.

Answer (score 1):

The general form for define is:

```
(define (desired-name-of-procedure item-1 item-2 item-3 ... item-n) 
        (; what to do with the items))
```

Another way to explain the behaviour of `define`, is in terms of "means of combination", and "means of abstraction".

[A] The **means of combination** in simple terms:

The syntax `(item-1 item-2 item-3 ... ... item-n)` is the fundamental means of combination provided by Scheme (and Lisp in general.)

- All code is a list represented using the above pattern
- The very first (leftmost) item is always treated as an operator
- Parentheses enforce the application of the operator... The leftmost item is required to accept all the items that follow, as arguments

[B] **means of abstraction** is simply; a way to name things.

An example will demonstrate how this all folds into the idea of the `define` primitive...

---

**Example--Arriving at `define` in a bottom-up way**

Consider this expression:

```
(lambda (x y) (* x y))
```

In plain English, the above expression translates to "Create a *nameless* procedure that accepts two arguments, and returns the value of the their product". Note that this generates a *nameless* procedure.

More accurately, **in terms of *means of combination***, Scheme provides us the keyword `lambda` as a primitive operator that creates user-defined procedures.

The leftmost item--`lambda`--is passed items `(x y)` and `(* x y)` as arguments, and the operator-application rule forces `lambda` to do something with the items.

The way `lambda` is defined internally causes it to parse the list `(x y)`, and treat `x` and `y` as arguments to pass to the list `(* x y)`, which `lambda` assumes is the user's definition of what to do when arguments `x` and `y` are encountered. Any value assigned to `x` and `y` will be processed in accordance with the rule `(* x y)`.

Enter, **means of abstraction**...

Suppose I wanted to refer to this type of multiplication at several places in my program, I might tweak the above lambda expression like this:

```
(define mul-two-things (lambda (x y) (* x y)))
```

`define` takes mul-two-things and the lambda expression as arguments, and *"binds"* them together. Now Scheme knows that `mul-two-things` should be associated with a procedure to take two arguments and return their product.

As it happens, the requirement of naming procedures is so very common and provides so much power of expression, that Scheme provides a cleaner-looking shortcut to do it.

Like @oscar-lopez says, `define` is the "special form" Scheme provides, to name things. And as far as Scheme's Interpreter is concerned, both the following definitions are identical:

```
(define (mul-two-things x y) (* x y))
(define mul-two-things (lambda (x y) (* x y))
```